# all elements within horizontal navigation on same height

Tags: html, css, navigation

I got a horizontal ul-li navigation. Inside the li elements are anchor elements. Some of those anchor elements have more lines of text than others, so they have different heights which looks quite crappy. The li elements have the same height (equal to the tallest anchor element).

Setting the anchor element height to 100% didn't do anything.

Solutions I know of right now:
- giving the anchor elements a fixed height
- use JS to scale the font size to ensure that all anchor elements have only one line of text
- use JS to equalize the height of the anchor elements once everything is loaded

I want to avoid using JS for styling purposes, and I'd like to keep the height dynamic instead of fixed, so that I don't have to update the css manually each time the content of an anchor element might change.

Is there any other option?

Thanks.

Comment: did you tried min-height / line-height? post your code in fiddle..

Comment: please give us some code

Comment: A fiddle will help here... Mean while you try setting line height and min height

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I created a fiddle. It misses the bootstrap part and some stuff, but shows the basic structure I guess. http://jsfiddle.net/F53UR/

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS3 Flex property `display:flex` Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qihafavi/1/edit)**.

```
ul{display:flex}

ul li{

 width:100px; 
 display:inline-block; 
 border:1px solid red;
}

a{background:gold; display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS table styles will help here

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/78F6Q/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Short text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Word</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Long long long text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto alias.</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: table;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
    width:25%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code centers the anchor tags nicely. But I was looking for a way to have the anchor elements be the same height and width as the li elements they are in, without using a fixed height. Sorry for the confusion.